# How to get randomly select n elements from a list using in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a list of vectors:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> num_dim, num_data = 10, 5
>>> data = np.random.rand(num_data, num_dim)
>>> data
array([[ 0.0498063 ,  0.18659463,  0.30563225,  0.99681495,  0.35692358,
         0.47759707,  0.85755606,  0.39373145,  0.54677259,  0.5168117 ],
       [ 0.18034536,  0.25935541,  0.79718771,  0.28604057,  0.17165293,
         0.90277904,  0.94016733,  0.15689765,  0.79758063,  0.41250143],
       [ 0.80716045,  0.84998745,  0.17893211,  0.36206016,  0.69604008,
         0.27249491,  0.92570247,  0.446499  ,  0.34424945,  0.08576628],
       [ 0.35311449,  0.67901964,  0.71023927,  0.03120829,  0.72864953,
         0.60717032,  0.8020118 ,  0.36047207,  0.46362718,  0.12441942],
       [ 0.1955419 ,  0.02702753,  0.76828842,  0.5438226 ,  0.69407709,
         0.20865243,  0.12783666,  0.81486189,  0.95583274,  0.30157658]])
```

From the `data`, I need to randomly pick 3 vectors, I could do it with:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(data, 3)
[array([ 0.80716045,  0.84998745,  0.17893211,  0.36206016,  0.69604008,
        0.27249491,  0.92570247,  0.446499  ,  0.34424945,  0.08576628]), array([ 0.18034536,  0.25935541,  0.79718771,  0.28604057,  0.17165293,
        0.90277904,  0.94016733,  0.15689765,  0.79758063,  0.41250143]), array([ 0.35311449,  0.67901964,  0.71023927,  0.03120829,  0.72864953,
        0.60717032,  0.8020118 ,  0.36047207,  0.46362718,  0.12441942])]
```

I've checked the docs at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html and I couldn't figure out whether there is such a functionality in `numpy` as `random.sample()`.

**Is it right that the `numpy.random.sample()` isn't the same as `random.sample()`?**

**Is there an equivalence of `random.sample()` in `numpy`?**

Comment: I think you are looking for `np.random.choice`. Although you need to pass `replace=False` for it to behave like `random.sample`.

Comment: What do you want to *do*?  What does `numpy.random.sample` do (or not do) that you want (or don't want) it to do?

Comment: @brenbarn I need to randomly pick n no. of elements from the list of vectors.

Comment: @ayhan, something like: `data[np.random.choice(range(len(data)), size=3, replace=False)]` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You don't need `range`. You can pass an integer, then it will make the selection from `np.arange(n)`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As @ayhan confirmed, it can be done as such:

```
>>> data[np.random.choice(len(data), size=3, replace=False)]
array([[ 0.80716045,  0.84998745,  0.17893211,  0.36206016,  0.69604008,
         0.27249491,  0.92570247,  0.446499  ,  0.34424945,  0.08576628],
       [ 0.35311449,  0.67901964,  0.71023927,  0.03120829,  0.72864953,
         0.60717032,  0.8020118 ,  0.36047207,  0.46362718,  0.12441942],
       [ 0.1955419 ,  0.02702753,  0.76828842,  0.5438226 ,  0.69407709,
         0.20865243,  0.12783666,  0.81486189,  0.95583274,  0.30157658]])
```

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

> **numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)**
>
> Generates a random sample from a given 1-D array

The `np.random.choice(data, size=3, replace=False)` selects 3 elements from the list of indices of the `data` without replacement.

Then `data[...]` slices the index and retrieve the indices selected with `np.random.choice`.