# Randomly selecting an element (float numbers, not integers) from an array python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a an array A:

```
A= np.array([[0.99, 0.1], [0.3,0.4], [0.1,0.5], [0.6,0.9], [0.4,0.2], [0.6, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6], [0.9, 0.2], [0.4 , 0.4], [0.7, 0.6]])
```

I am trying to randomly select one of these vectors. I am aware there is `random.randin` and `random.choice`, however it doesn't work with floats.

I have tried:

```
X = np.random.uniform(2,size=1)
print(A[X[0],:])
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: see also: [How to get randomly select n elements from a list using in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39563859/10197418)

Answer (score 3):

Use `random.choice` :)

```
import numpy as np
import random

A= np.array([[0.99, 0.1], [0.3,0.4], [0.1,0.5], [0.6,0.9], [0.4,0.2], [0.6, 0.3], [0.5, 0.6], [0.9, 0.2], [0.4 , 0.4], [0.7, 0.6]])

print(random.choice(A))
```